# Parse Json object of unpredictable type name

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to parse a JSON answer from a RESTfull Api. I'm usally using NewtonSoft Json.Net to deserialize objects (whith the help of tools like Json2Csharp).

This time though, the answer I get from the webservice is more complex.

The answer is like as follow : (see full answer [here](http://pastebin.com/Ns9FPKdt))

```
[
    {
        "semester": 0,
        "modules": {
            "B-ANG-052": {...},
            "B-ANG-056": {...},
            ...
    },
    {
        "semester": 1,
        "modules": {
            "BSU-CPR-125": {...},
            "BSU-BPR-098": {...},
            ...
    },
    ...
[
```

Problem is, objects `B-ANG-052`, `B-ANG-056`, `BSU-CPR-125` and `BSU-BPR-098` are same type, **but their number and name vary, and I cannot predict their name and number ahead of query**.

Idealy, I would like to be able to create something like

```
public class ModuleRessource
{
    // B-ANG-052 & Co stuff
}
public class Modules
{
    public List<ModuleRessource> Modules { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int semester { get; set; }
    public Modules Modules { get; set; }
}
```

But obviously Json.Net throws an Exeption when I try to do that.

I would very appreciate some help on the matter, because I haven't been able to find any clue.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Modules
{
    public List<ModuleRessource> Modules { get; set; }
}
```

Change this to:

```
public class Modules {
    public Dictionary<string, someObject> { get; set; }
}
```

`someObject` should be whatever is in `{...}` with the key `B-ANG-052`. This only works if the keys are unique, of course. Then you can grab the dictionary's keys and use them to loop through and grab the `someObject`. I don't really know how you're going to be able to create an object and use that object without ever knowing what the object is called. If the `{...}` is always the same, create a class and deserialize it to a `someObject` in the dictionary.

You could also try to use a dynamic type, but you'll still run into the problem of not knowing what the object is called. You'd to use reflection to loop through the properties of your main object then to retrieve them.

Comment: Thank you for the rapid answer ! I'll try it right away :)